# Extracting year and month from one column and insert it into another

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

I have this MySQL table:

```
Act (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type VARCHAR(20),
  act_date datetime,
  year INT,
  month INT,
  place VARCHAR(20)
  );
```

I filled columns of this table with random values accept for columns 'year' and 'month'. I want to fill my 'year' column with the year that I have in 'act_date' column and do the same with 'month' column (fill it with month numbers from 'act_date' column). I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you can use `Month()` and `Year()`, for further reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an awful idea, but here you go:

```
UPDATE Act
   SET `year` = YEAR(`act_date`)
     , `month` = MONTH(`act_date`);
```

Comment: Thank you, what would be better then? Doing a separate Table Time with columns year and month? I really need to have these two values.

Comment: Don't store redundant data in your tables. If you want to get the month or year of a particular date, you can use the very same functions in your `SELECT` query.